# Как можно распределить трафик

Tags: трафик

Есть 3 выделенных сервера три канала.Есть 1 файл.Сервера у разных провайдеров.Как можно распределить трафик между ними, в идеале хотелось бы чтобы запрос файла шел только к 1 домену.

Comment: Вы один файл хотите качать с 3 серверов но какбэ с одного? Аля что б скорость больше была?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS round-robin что ли.

В общем, для динамического распределения трафика нужен тот, кто будет распределять. Плюс, наверное хочется распределения на основании каких-нибудь фактов, типа геолокации.

Если для файла не важен MIME-тип и размер позволяет -- можешь вообще заюзать github/dropbox как CDN.